# Javascript class variables scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, oop, scope

I'm kinda struggling with Javascript variable scopes in combination with a jQuery JSON call.
Unforutnatly, I can't post this script on jsFiddle, because it needs some data.

I'm trying to dynamicly load data and output it on the user's screen.
I've now only created the method that loads the data for the first time. Later on I'd like to make an update method which updates the data in the table rows.

But now I'm having a problem with the variable scope.
When $.pcw.outstandingInvoices.init() has been called, I get the following error:

```
ypeError: can't convert undefined to object
this.outstandingInvoicesArray[key] = entry;
```

My code:

```
-- Post is getting to long, so removed the first code i've used. --
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong so I can fix it?

Thanks in advance!

--- UPDATE ---
I've edited the things you guys told me, but still I'm getting errors... Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

My new code and errors:

```
-- Post is getting to long, so removed the first update of the code. --
```

Errors:

```
Initializing outstandingInvoices class.
Loading outstanding invoices from server.

TypeError: context.outstandingInvoicesObject is undefined
if (context.outstandingInvoicesObject.length == 0) {

TypeError: can't convert undefined to object
self.outstandingInvoicesObject[key] = entry;
```

-- UPDATE 2 -- 
Just edited my code and now I'm not gettting errors, but the data in outstandingInvoicesObject is not properly saved, so the method addOutstandingInvoicesTable can't find any invoices.
I've been analyzing the console and it seems the there is somethin wrong with order of execution of the methods...

The code:

```
$.pcw.outstandingInvoices = function () {
    var context = this;
    context.outstandingInvoicesObject = [];

    context.init = function ()
    {
        console.log('Initializing outstandingInvoices class.');

        context.loadData();        
        context.removeLoader();
        context.addOutstandingInvoicesToTable();
    };

    context.loadData = function ()
    {
        console.log('Loading outstanding invoices from server.');

        jQuery.getJSON('/ajax/outgoing-invoices/find-outstanding.json', function (data)
        {   
            var i = 0;
            jQuery.each(data, function (key, entry)
            {
                context.outstandingInvoicesObject[key] = entry;

                ++i;
            });

            console.log('Loaded ' + i + ' invoices');
        }).error(function () {
            console.error('Error while loading outstanding invoices.');
        });
    };

    context.removeLoader = function ()
    {
        console.log('Removing loader');

        jQuery('table#invoices-outstanding tr.ajax-loader').fadeOut();
    };

    context.addOutstandingInvoicesToTable = function()
    {
        console.log('Outputing invoices to table');

        if (context.outstandingInvoicesObject.length == 0) {
            console.log('No outstanding invoices found');
        }

        jQuery.each(context.outstandingInvoicesObject, function (key, entry)
        {
            // This is a new outstanding invoice
            var rowClass = 'info';

            switch(entry.status)
            {
                case 'Created':
                case 'Sent':
                case 'Paid': // The invoices with Paid statuses aren't show here, because we only show the oustanding invoices on this page.
                    rowClass = 'success';
                break;

                case 'First reminder':
                case 'Second reminder':
                case 'Partially paid':
                    rowClass = 'warning';
                break;

                case 'Third reminder':
                case 'Collection agency':
                case 'Judicial proceedings':
                    rowClass = 'error';
                break;
            }

            jQuery('table#invoices-outstanding tbody').append(
                outstandingInvoice = jQuery('<tr/>', {
                    id: 'outgoing-invoice-' + key,
                    class: rowClass
                }).append(
                    jQuery('<td/>', {
                        class: 'id',
                        text: key
                    })
                ).append(
                    jQuery('<td/>', {
                        class: 'debtor-name',
                        text: entry.debtor_name
                    })
                ).append(
                    jQuery('<td/>', {
                        class: 'amount',
                        text: entry.amount
                    })
                ).append(
                    jQuery('<td/>', {
                        class: 'date',
                        text: entry.created_timestamp
                    })
                ).append(
                    jQuery('<td/>', {
                        class: 'status',
                        text: entry.status
                    })
                ).append(
                    jQuery('<td/>', {
                        class: 'creator',
                        text: entry.creator
                    })
                )            
            );
        });
    }
}


// When document is ready
(function()
{
    var invoices = new $.pcw.outstandingInvoices();
    invoices.init();
})();
```

The console output:

```
Initializing outstandingInvoices class.

Loading outstanding invoices from server.
GET /ajax/outgoing-invoices/find-outstanding.json
200 OK
509ms   

Removing loader

Outputing invoices to table

No outstanding invoices found

Loaded 29 invoices
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you add some data samples as JSON string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems are solved now.. It was a combination of the things you guys said and the problem that the AJAX call was asynchronous.

The final working code is:

```
$.pcw.outstandingInvoices = function () {
    var context = this;
    context.outstandingInvoicesObject = new Object();

    context.init = function ()
    {
        console.log('Initializing outstandingInvoices class.');

        context.loadData();                
        context.removeLoader();
        context.addOutstandingInvoicesToTable();
    };

    context.loadData = function ()
    {
        console.log('Loading outstanding invoices from server.');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/outgoing-invoices/find-outstanding.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {                
                var i = 0;            
                jQuery.each(data, function (invoiceId, invoiceDetails)
                {
                    context.outstandingInvoicesObject[invoiceId] = invoiceDetails;

                    ++i;                                
                });

                console.log('Loaded ' + i + ' invoices');       
            }
        }).error(function () {
            console.error('Error while loading outstanding invoices.');
        });
    };

    context.removeLoader = function ()
    {
        console.log('Removing loader');

        jQuery('table#invoices-outstanding tr.ajax-loader').fadeOut();
    };

    context.addOutstandingInvoicesToTable = function()
    {
        console.log('Outputing invoices to table');           

        if (context.outstandingInvoicesObject.length == 0) {
            console.log('No outstanding invoices found');            
        }

        jQuery.each(context.outstandingInvoicesObject, function (key, entry)
        {
            // This is a new outstanding invoice
            var rowClass = 'info';

            switch(entry.status)
            {
                case 'Created':
                case 'Sent':
                case 'Paid': // The invoices with Paid statuses aren't show here, because we only show the oustanding invoices on this page.
                    rowClass = 'success';
                break;

                case 'First reminder':
                case 'Second reminder':
                case 'Partially paid':
                    rowClass = 'warning';
                break;

                case 'Third reminder':
                case 'Collection agency':
                case 'Judicial proceedings':
                    rowClass = 'error';
                break;
            }

            jQuery('table#invoices-outstanding tbody').append(
                outstandingInvoice = jQuery('<tr/>', {
                    id: 'outgoing-invoice-' + key,
                    class: rowClass
                }).append(
                    jQuery('<td/>', {
                        class: 'id',
                        text: key
                    })
                ).append(
                    jQuery('<td/>', {
                        class: 'debtor-name',
                        text: entry.debtor_name
                    })
                ).append(
                    jQuery('<td/>', {
                        class: 'amount',
                        text: entry.amount
                    })
                ).append(
                    jQuery('<td/>', {
                        class: 'date',
                        text: entry.created_timestamp
                    })
                ).append(
                    jQuery('<td/>', {
                        class: 'status',
                        text: entry.status
                    })
                ).append(
                    jQuery('<td/>', {
                        class: 'creator',
                        text: entry.creator
                    })
                )            
            );
        });
    }
}

// When document is ready
(function()
{   
    var invoices = new $.pcw.outstandingInvoices();
    invoices.init();
})();
```

Thanks for the help, guys!

Answer (score 1):

Create a backup of the object so you can use it in functions where `this` does not reference the object.

```
loadData: function ()
{
    console.log('Loading outstanding invoices from server.');
    var self = this;
    jQuery.getJSON('/ajax/outgoing-invoices/find-outstanding.json', function (data)
    {            
        jQuery.each(data, function (key, entry)
        {
            self.outstandingInvoicesArray[key] = entry;
        });
    }).error(function () {
        console.error('Error while loading outstanding invoices.');
    });
},
```

Comment: Did this, thank you. Untortunatly this did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating `outstandingInvoicesArray` as an array, but you're trying to access it as an object:

```
outstandingInvoicesArray: []
[...]
this.outstandingInvoicesArray[key] = entry;
```

create it as an object instead:

```
outstandingInvoicesArray: {}
```

Comment: Did this, thank you. Untortunatly this did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the *new* keyword when initailizing the object if you want to use *this*:

```
$.pcw.outstandingInvoices = function(){
   var context = this;//replace every instance of "this" in your class with the context var

   context.init= function ()
    {
        console.log('Initializing outstandingInvoices class.');

        context.loadData();

    }
    //the rest of functions defined below
}
var invoices = new $.pcw.outstandingInvoices();
invoices.init();
```

Edit: to fix the remaining errors try using context instead of self, and declare outstandingInvoicesObject on the context:

```
$.pcw.outstandingInvoices = function () {
    var context = this;
    context.outstandingInvoicesObject = [];

    context.init = function ()
    {
        console.log('Initializing outstandingInvoices class.');

        context.loadData();

    };

    context.loadData = function ()
    {
        console.log('Loading outstanding invoices from server.');



        jQuery.getJSON('/ajax/outgoing-invoices/find-outstanding.json', function (data)
        {            
            jQuery.each(data, function (key, entry)
            {
                context.outstandingInvoicesObject[key] = entry;
            });
            //now that we have data, call add the invoices to the table
            context.removeLoader();
            context.addOutstandingInvoicesToTable();
        }).error(function () {
            console.error('Error while loading outstanding invoices.');
        });
    };

    context.removeLoader = function ()
    {
        jQuery('table#invoices-outstanding tr.ajax-loader').fadeOut();
    };

    context.addOutstandingInvoicesToTable = function()
    {
        if (context.outstandingInvoicesObject.length == 0) {
            console.log('No outstanding invoices found');
        }

        jQuery.each(context.outstandingInvoicesObject, function (key, entry)
        {
            // This is a new outstanding invoice
            var rowClass = 'info';

            switch(entry.status)
            {
                case 'Created':
                case 'Sent':
                case 'Paid': // The invoices with Paid statuses aren't show here, because we only show the oustanding invoices on this page.
                    rowClass = 'success';
                break;

                case 'First reminder':
                case 'Second reminder':
                case 'Partially paid':
                    rowClass = 'warning';
                break;

                case 'Third reminder':
                case 'Collection agency':
                case 'Judicial proceedings':
                    rowClass = 'error';
                break;
            }

            jQuery('table#invoices-outstanding tbody').append(
                outstandingInvoice = jQuery('<tr/>', {
                    id: 'outgoing-invoice-' + key,
                    class: rowClass
                }).append(
                    jQuery('<td/>', {
                        class: 'id',
                        text: key
                    })
                ).append(
                    jQuery('<td/>', {
                        class: 'debtor-name',
                        text: entry.debtor_name
                    })
                ).append(
                    jQuery('<td/>', {
                        class: 'amount',
                        text: entry.amount
                    })
                ).append(
                    jQuery('<td/>', {
                        class: 'date',
                        text: entry.created_timestamp
                    })
                ).append(
                    jQuery('<td/>', {
                        class: 'status',
                        text: entry.status
                    })
                ).append(
                    jQuery('<td/>', {
                        class: 'creator',
                        text: entry.creator
                    })
                )            
            );
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Did this, thank you. Untortunatly this did not fix the problem.

Comment: add context to the delcaration.  so context.outstandingInvoicesObject = [] instead of var outstandingInvoicesObject = [];  also instead of using the self variable, use context.outstandingInvoicesObject[key] = entry;

Comment: I posted your code sample updated with these fixes that I suggested in the comments above

Comment: Just replaced the comma's with semicolons after each of the function declarations

Comment: Thank you! I've used your code, added some console.log() calls to it to analyze. Now I'm not getting errors anymore, but the var outstandingInvoicesObject seems to be empty when the method addOutstandingInvoicesToTable is called.... But the strange thing is that the var outstandingInvoicesObject  is fille by the method loadData which finds 29 outstanding invoices.. Please see the start post to see the updated code and the firebug console logs.. Hope you can find the problem.. Thanks!

Comment: @E.Clark This is happening because the call to get json is async, so when you populate the table the object has not yet been filled.  I edited my answer so that the call call to populate the table happens in the callback of the get json method

Answer (score 1):

The following should fix your problems. You weren't declaring oustandingInvoicesObject the way you were intending. It had to be off 'this' or 'context' in your case.

Also, you declared oustandingInvoicesObject as an Array instead of an Object. You can't add properties to an Array like you would an Object.

Let me know how it goes.

```
$.pcw.outstandingInvoices = function () {
    var context = this;
    context.outstandingInvoicesObject = {};

    context.init = function ()
    {
        console.log('Initializing outstandingInvoices class.');

        context.loadData();
        context.removeLoader();
        context.addOutstandingInvoicesToTable();
    };

    context.loadData = function ()
    {
        console.log('Loading outstanding invoices from server.');

        var self = this;

        jQuery.getJSON('/ajax/outgoing-invoices/find-outstanding.json', function (data)
        {            
            jQuery.each(data, function (key, entry)
            {
                self.outstandingInvoicesObject[key] = entry;
            });
        }).error(function () {
            console.error('Error while loading outstanding invoices.');
        });
    };

    context.removeLoader = function ()
    {
        jQuery('table#invoices-outstanding tr.ajax-loader').fadeOut();
    };

    context.addOutstandingInvoicesToTable = function()
    {
        if (context.outstandingInvoicesObject.length == 0) {
            console.log('No outstanding invoices found');
        }

        jQuery.each(context.outstandingInvoicesObject, function (key, entry)
        {
            // This is a new outstanding invoice
            var rowClass = 'info';

            switch(entry.status)
            {
                case 'Created':
                case 'Sent':
                case 'Paid': // The invoices with Paid statuses aren't show here, because we only show the oustanding invoices on this page.
                    rowClass = 'success';
                break;

                case 'First reminder':
                case 'Second reminder':
                case 'Partially paid':
                    rowClass = 'warning';
                break;

                case 'Third reminder':
                case 'Collection agency':
                case 'Judicial proceedings':
                    rowClass = 'error';
                break;
            }

            jQuery('table#invoices-outstanding tbody').append(
                outstandingInvoice = jQuery('<tr/>', {
                    id: 'outgoing-invoice-' + key,
                    class: rowClass
                }).append(
                    jQuery('<td/>', {
                        class: 'id',
                        text: key
                    })
                ).append(
                    jQuery('<td/>', {
                        class: 'debtor-name',
                        text: entry.debtor_name
                    })
                ).append(
                    jQuery('<td/>', {
                        class: 'amount',
                        text: entry.amount
                    })
                ).append(
                    jQuery('<td/>', {
                        class: 'date',
                        text: entry.created_timestamp
                    })
                ).append(
                    jQuery('<td/>', {
                        class: 'status',
                        text: entry.status
                    })
                ).append(
                    jQuery('<td/>', {
                        class: 'creator',
                        text: entry.creator
                    })
                )            
            );
        });
    };
};

// When document is ready
(function(){
    var invoices = new $.pcw.outstandingInvoices();
    invoices.init();
})();
```

Comment: Thank you! Also tried this one, but the same problem remains.. Please see my updated code in the start post.